# Persist guava cache on shutdown

Tags: java, guava

I use the following guava cache to store messages for a specific time waiting for a possible response. So I use the cache more like a timeout for messages:

```
Cache cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(7, TimeUnit.DAYS).build();
cache.put(id,message);
...
cache.getIfPresent(id);
```

In the end I need to persist the messages with its currently 'timeout' information on shutdown
and restore it on startup with the internal already expired times per entry. I couldn't find any methods which give me access to the time information, so I can handle it by myself.

The [gauva wiki](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) says:

> Your application will not need to store more data than what would fit in RAM. (Guava caches are local to a single run of your application. They do not store data in files, or on outside servers. If this does not fit your needs, consider a tool like Memcached.)

Do you think this restriction address also a 'timeout' map to persist on shutdown?

Comment: In case you were thinking of serializing the whole cache, that won't work: "The caches produced by CacheBuilder are serializable, and the deserialized caches retain all the configuration properties of the original cache. Note that the serialized form does not include cache contents, but only configuration." So you probably need to replace Guava Cache with a more complete cache implementation, as suggested by the wiki you quoted.

Comment: You are right with the keyword serializing, sorry I didn't used it directly.

But is there a way to get the expiring time information out of the Cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way to recreate the cache with per-entry expiration values -- even if you do use reflection.  You might be able to simulate it by using a `DelayedQueue` in a separate thread that explicitly invalidates entries that should have expired, but that's the best I think you can do.

That said, if you're just interested in peeking at the expiration information, I would recommend wrapping your cache values in a class that remembers the expiration time, so you can look up the expiration time for an entry just by looking up its value and calling a `getExpirationTime()` method or what have you.

That approach, at least, should not break with new Guava releases.

Comment: I didn't used the guava cache for performance reasons, but rather because it seemed to be a very simple solution for timeout objects. In the end there is missing a way to make the cache survive a application shutdown for any reasons. So in the end I now decided to directly persist the object with a timestamp and let a scheduled thread cleanup the timed out objects. Costs a lot more lines of code but fits my needs better. Thank you all so far.

Answer (score 1):

Well, unfortunately Guava doesn't seem to expose this functionality but if you feel adventurous and absolutely must have this you could always use reflection. Just look at sources and see what methods do you need. As always care should be taken as your code might break when Guaval internal implementation changes. Code below seems to work with Guava 10.0.1:

```
    Cache<Integer, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(7, TimeUnit.DAYS).build(new CacheLoader<Integer, String>() {
        @Override
        public String load(Integer key) throws Exception {
            return "The value is "+key.toString();
        }
    });
    Integer key_1 = Integer.valueOf(1);
    Integer key_2 = Integer.valueOf(2);
    
    System.out.println(cache.get(key_1));
    System.out.println(cache.get(key_2));
    
    ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> map = cache.asMap();
    
    Method m = map.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getEntry", Object.class);
    m.setAccessible(true);

    for(Integer key: map.keySet()) {
        Object value = m.invoke(map, key);
        Method m2 = value.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getExpirationTime", null);
        m2.setAccessible(true);
        Long expirationTime = (Long)m2.invoke(value, null);
        System.out.println(key+" expiration time is "+expirationTime);
    }
```

Comment: And obviously vice-versa for rebuild the cache. I have the possibility to change the design and switch to a directly persisted version. Too bad, guava cache looks otherwise really nice!

Comment: We recommend very strongly against this approach, not least because it will break on new Guava versions.

Comment: Absolutely agree, I said just that in original post :)